# getting problem on using useContext in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, use-context

### I have a simple react app in which i have to use useContext.

(btw im using vite + react)

here is my code for Context.jsx

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';

const emailContext = React.createContext();

export const useEmail = () => useContext(emailContext);

export const emailProvider = ({children}) => {
  const currentUser = "None";

  const value = {
    currentUser
  }

  return(
    <emailContext.Provider value={value}>
      {children}
      </emailContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

and heres how i am using the context

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useEmail } from "./Context/Context"

export default function App() {

  const {currentUser} = useEmail();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox {currentUser}</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am sure why I am getting error in this code.

##### some of the errors that I am getting

- _useEmail is undefined (latest)
- currentUser user is undefined

thing i have tried

- Initialized createContext with some initial value (only intial value is visible).
- using useContext() directy in the App.js (useContext(emailContext) return undefined)
- instead of {children} used `<children/>`.
- used useState instead of const currentUser in emailProvider

##### I am getting same problem even when I use typescript.

but none of the above helped.

Comment: I have read some implemetation on the same for global state management with `context api` you can check it out. Provides a detailed look on the global state. Here is the link [Similar implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69870459/how-manage-global-state-using-context-api-in-react-js)

Comment: I think it's a [vite issue](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/3301).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrapping app with `<emailProvider></emailProvider>` to using data in `value={value}`. Now it gets undefined from `const emailContext = React.createContext();`

Comment: ```export default function App() {
  var value  = useEmail();
  console.log(value)

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <EmailProvider>
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      </EmailProvider>
    </div>
  );
}``` Even after this the code is not working, If place ```value.currentUser``` in the inside the ```EmailProvider``` component it will throw an error

Answer (score 0):

Below code may help you analyse the flow , also check link for more details  https://medium.com/technofunnel/usecontext-in-react-hooks-aa9a60b8a461

use `useContext` in receiving end

```
 import React, { useState } from "react";

var userDetailContext = React.createContext(null);

export default function UserDetailsComponent() {
  var [userDetails] = useState({
    name: "Mayank",
    age: 30
  });

  return (
    <userDetailContext.Provider value={userDetails}>
      <h1>This is the Parent Component</h1>
      <hr />
      <ChildComponent userDetails={userDetails} />
    </userDetailContext.Provider>
  );
}

function ChildComponent(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>This is Child Component</h2>
      <hr />
      <SubChildComponent />
    </div>
  );
}

function SubChildComponent(props) {
  var contextData = React.useContext(userDetailContext);
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>This is Sub Child Component</h3>
      <h4>User Name: {contextData.name}</h4>
      <h4>User Age: {contextData.age}</h4>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: On same file it working, but if the files are different it is not working. Also, I have to pass components dynamically. For the medium page, I cannot view it because it requires subscription.

Answer (score 0):

in index.js/main.js file

`<emailProvider/> <App/> <emailProvider>`

this helped me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).